# Reducing lag when updating cells in a HTML Excel-like spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

## The Situation

Okay, so here's the deal: I've set myself a challenge to improve my JavaScript knowledge. This challenge involves the creation of an entirely front-end Excel-like spreadsheet. Currently what I have is a table with 15 columns and 30 rows of table cells which allow text input. Just like in Excel, each cell has its own unique reference ID (A2, F14, G9, etc.):

```
           _________________
     _____|__A__|__B__|__C__|
    |__1__|__8__|_____|_____|
    |__2__|_100_|__6__|_____|
    |__3__|_300_|_____|__5__| etc...
```

These cells will allow live Excel-like formulae to be placed inside, and the spreadsheet will update itself accordingly, for example:

```
           _____________________
     _____|__________C__________|
    |__1__| =(SUM(A1:A3)*C3)+B2 |

    Would translate to: var n = ((8+100+300)*5)+6;
```

## The Problem

Now this is all good, but here is the problem: every time I update just one cell, I have to loop through and update all cells to ensure the data is accurate. This isn't a great issue when there are only 9 cells available like in the crude example above, but my current table has 15 columns and 30 rows... 450 of them!

I currently have it set up so that every time the browser's focus leaves a cell, the behind JavaScript loops through and updates each cell to ensure the data is all correct. This on its own causes a tiny bit of lag when there are only 5 or 6 cells with data in, so I'm concerned that by the time I populate every cell in the spreadsheet my browser will die on me.

I'm most likely dreaming the impossible, but ideally I'd like to be able to present a spreadsheet with hundreds of columns and rows which update on the fly. So my two questions to you all are:

- What can I do to prevent lag?
- Would it even be possible to support more than 15 columns and 30 rows of formulae without breaking the internet in the process?

Comment: Why do you have to loop through each cell? the formula only affects 'this' cell and you can hold the values of the other cells in an array, only changing the array when a table cell value changes.

Comment: Because if, for example, that formula was in C1 and D1 referenced C1, D1 would need its value updating. If I was to store all the values in an array I'd still need to update the values every time a cell was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good solution would be to deal with callbacks instead of iterating all over the table.

Each time you create a new formula, you should look for the referenced cells in that formula and add a handler for changing the cell calling that referenced cell every time the latter changes.

I created a [very quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/cKu97/1/) of what I mean. Be careful using it, It may be very buggy, since I don't clean the referenced cells once you change the formula. Anyway, I think it may look clear as an example.

The core of the idea lies in the following snippet

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
  var referencedCells = getReferencedCells($(this).val());
  var $referencer = $(this);  

  for(var i=0 ; i<referencedCells.length; i++){  
    $(referencedCells[i]).on('change', function(){  
      updateValue($referencer);
    });
  }

  updateValue($referencer);

});
```

Suppose every cell is an `input`. Every time it changes, you look for the referenced cells in the formula, and add a callback for them. Thus, when you change those cells, your formula value will update, without looking for all the cells that in their formula call the one that you changed.

**Edit**: Every cell accepts **only sums** NOT starting with "=" (e.g.: A2+B2+3) (with no spaces) **or literals**. The result is shown in an alert since changing the actual value would mess up the formula (in real life you could accomplish this saving the actual value in an attribute). Don't try any formula that shouldn't work in nice cases (anything that in excel would show something different than a number).

Comment: This looks promising! Currently I have each formula stored within each cell's data attribute, so that's already accounted for. At work at the moment but will give this a try later, thanks!

Comment: Btw, just noticed that this simplified version will not work when you reference cells that have formulas instead of literals. Also, it will get into an infinite loop if you have circular references. I'll see if I can fix the first problem later... I'm at work, too.

Comment: Ok, I edited the example, adding a simple recursive function for calculating the value of cells, always without iterating all over the table.

Comment: Sam, wouldn't this allow you to add multiple identical "change" listeners  to a single cell? For example, B6 references A1 and you "change" B6 twice, wouldn't you essentially be adding two separate "change" listeners to cell A1 that are identical?

Comment: @Jack, that's exactly what I meant when I said _"It may be very buggy, since I don't clean the referenced cells once you change the formula"._ Anyway, that shouldn't be hard to solve: you just have to unbind the previous handlers every time you change the formula.

Comment: @Jack I read again you comment and that is not _exactly_ what I meant. What I meant was that if I call a cell in a formula, and then I change the formula, with the new formula **not** calling that cell, then every time I change that cell, the `input` containing the formula will try to update, because the handler is still there removed. Anyway, what you say would also happen if you change from one formula to another one containing repeated cells.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run the "refresh" on every single cell. When one cell is updated, if there is a function in it, it is going to reference a particular cell, row, or column. Since it contains that reference, you can parse it to determine what cells need to be updated. For example your `=(SUM(A1:A3)*C3)+B2` knows it only needs the values from A1, A2, A3, C3, and B2 - so instead of looping through everything you can directly reference those cells. Since you know the last cell to be updated with your listener, you can parse what data that cell references then only run your script on those cells (should the data in the cell that triggered the event require an update). You are controlling all the functions and the way users select data so you know when something needs to be updated.

Comment: In response to your 2nd comment on the question, if using my example above, cell A1 referenced some other cells, you could parse the data in that cell and complete whatever action you need to on the related cells. You can simple run a foreach on every referenced cell and inside that, check to see if any other cells are referenced and keep drilling down recursively until you  get to the end.

Comment: Wouldn't that still risk making the site lag every time a referenced cell is changed? If B1 is the initially referenced cell and that changes, not only the cells that reference B1 need to be updated, but all the cells that reference the cells that have been updated also need updating. Would it be better to, if possible, gradually update the necessary cells rather than attempting to do it all in one go?

Comment: Well, of course SOME operations will require some lag - that'll happen in Excel as well. But, as opposed to the way you have it above, not every single firing of any event on the spreadsheet will cause lag. Also, these longer operations will STILL be shorter than any single operation causing the entire table to refresh because you are still not updating the entire table. This is the best possible way to do it.

Comment: Also, since you control all the operations on the table, you know that for example, the SUM function will not change any cells except the one it is being called on. Because of that, you don't have to iterate through all the referenced cells references because they will not be updated. However, if you were doing some type of writing operation, you would have to drill all the way down recursively. But, since you control everything you won't have to do this every time - only when it is needed.